# Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] when using ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```js
angular.module('app',[])
  .controller('myCtrl',function() {
    this.items = m;
});

var m = {
    "India": "4",
    "England": "2",
    "Brazil": "3",
    "UK": "1",
    "USA": "3",
    "Syria": "2"
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

  <h3>FIFA Mactch Summary:</h3>
  <div ng-app='app' ng-controller="myCtrl">
      <ul>
          <li ng-repeat="(country,goals) in items">{{country}}: {{goals}}</li>
      </ul>
  </div>

</body>
```

Above is my code. When I run it, got Uncaught Error [$injector:modulerr] error. I can not figure out why get this error. Anyone could help me? Really appreciate that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for you to access Angular properties in the DOM, you need to establish a scope and inject `$scope` as a dependency in your controller, which you do by placing it in the function argument. Then you need to assign your `items` to something on the scope object for it to be accessed in the DOM. For it to work, it should look something like this. Additionally, I'd avoid something like the `m` object floating outside the controller. If your only using something in one controller, I'd say it's best to keep the information inside that controller.

```js
angular.module('app',[])
  .controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.items = {
    "India": "4",
    "England": "2",
    "Brazil": "3",
    "UK": "1",
    "USA": "3",
    "Syria": "2"
    };
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

  <h3>FIFA Mactch Summary:</h3>
  <div ng-app='app' ng-controller="myCtrl">
      <ul>
          <li ng-repeat="(country,goals) in items">{{country}}: {{goals}}</li>
      </ul>
  </div>

</body>
```

Comment: Thank you so much!